# How to save and load multiple photos into my local app in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

```
     -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.images addObject:image];
    [self.maintable reloadData];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
    -(IBAction)savebutton:(id)sender{

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask , YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat: @"MyImages"]];

        for (int i=0; i<_images.count; i++) {
            image=[_images objectAtIndex:i];

            NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"saved");
        }
    }

- (UIImage*)loadImage   
        {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);`
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat: @"MyImage.png"] ];

                image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
                if(image != nil){

                    [self.images addObject:image];
                }

               return image;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on correct track,
On save button action, save images document directory's particular path and save image name in one array which you need to save in core data or preference whatever you preferred in your app
like this..

```
NSString *strImageName = @"image.png"
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: strImageName]; 
// Above you can give your custom path like @"App_Name/imageName" for unique identification

[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
[arrCoreData addObject: strImageName];
```

Once you have done(saved all your images then save image name in preference)
like this

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: arrCoreData];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"MyImageArray"];
```

When you want to fetch images and display it again,
You may follow this flow:

```
NSData *mainCatData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyImageArray"];
arrCoreData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:mainCatData];
```

Then using these images name you may fetch images back and display as you want..

To load image from document directory, You may use this function

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage:(NSString)strImageName{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString: @"AppName/%@", strImageName] ];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
return image;
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it and worked on my app:)

```
 - (void)loadImage
    {   
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
        NSArray *fileArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];    
        for (int i=0; i<fileArray.count; i++) { 
            NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileArray[i]];           
            image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
            [self.images addObject:image];
        }
    }

    -(IBAction)savebutton:(id)sender{
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,                                                          NSUserDomainMask , YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        for (int i=0; i<_images.count; i++) {
            NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat: @"MyImages%d", i]];
            image=[_images objectAtIndex:i];
            NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"saved");
        }
    }
```